# I would like to know if the IBM Websphere MQ Web Console and REST API Licence is extra paid or it is included with the Basic IBM MQ server

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to know if the Basic IBM MQ Server licence cost, covers also the IBM Websphere MQ web console and the REST API.

Comment: It was introduced at v9.1 LTS and 9.0 CD, it is part of the product and not a separate entitlement.

Answer (score 1):

As [JoshMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7264620/joshmc) already answered in the comments: The MQ Console and MQ REST API are part of the MQ product.

These components are also not specifically mentioned on the [IBM MQ licensing page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q126140_.htm) as a separate product, so it complies to the "All other IBM MQ components from the install media not explicitly mentioned above" rule.